# RewriteRule set cookie and remove string

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, cookies

I'm trying to set a cookie through a RewriteRule, and force it to remove the string form the url once it has set the cookie. Here are my rules:

#### .htaccess

```
RewriteCond     %{HTTP_HOST}            ^www.oneblis.com$       [NC]
RewriteRule     ^(.*)$               http://oneblis.com/$1  [R=301,L]

RewriteCond     %{QUERY_STRING}         ^en/?$
RewriteRule     (.*)            $1?             [R,NC,L,CO=lang:en:.oneblis.com]

RewriteCond     %{QUERY_STRING}         ^es/?$
RewriteRule     (.*)            $1?             [R,NC,L,CO=lang:es:.oneblis.com]
```

Though, oneblis.com/en/ turns out a 404. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this is the following:

#### .htaccess

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule (.*)(es|en)/$   $1? [R,CO=lang:$2:.oneblis.com:43200:/]
```